# How do I use not_expression and a regular filter expression together using PHP in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: php, filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have been able to use not_expression successfully to exclude words from a dimension, but now I need a dimensionFilter that excludes words, but also includes a certain word.

Here's what I have so far that doesn't work:

```
'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
            'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
            'value' => 'specific-word',
        ])
    ]),
    'not_expression' => new FilterExpression([
        'or_group' => new FilterExpressionList([
            'expressions' => [
                new FilterExpression([
                    'filter' => new Filter([
                        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
                            'value' => 'some-word',
                        ])
                    ])
                ]),
                new FilterExpression([
                    'filter' => new Filter([
                        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
                            'value' => 'some-word',
                        ])
                    ])
                ]),
                new FilterExpression([
                    'filter' => new Filter([
                        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
                        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
                            'value' => 'some-word',
                        ])
                    ])
                ]),
            ]
        ])    
    ])        
]),
```

If I remove this:

```
'filter' => new Filter([
    'field_name' => 'pagePath',
    'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
        'match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
        'value' => 'review',
    ])
]),
```

It works. And if I have only it, it works. I need both to be true.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have two groups of conditions, you have to relate them with the grouping you want (AND, OR...).

Also, in the exclusion I recommend that you use [inListFilter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression#inlistfilter) instead of string and then you only have to write one condition:

```
    'dimensionFilter' => new new FilterExpression([
        'and_group' => new FilterExpressionList([
            'expressions' =>
            [
                'and_group' => new FilterExpression([
                    /* pagePath = specific-word */
                ])
            ],
            [
                'not_expression' => new FilterExpression([
                    /* pagePath IN (some-word-1,some-word-2,some-word-3) >> with Filter > inListFilter */
                ])
            ]
        ])
    ])
```

Comment: I tried testing this out a couple different ways and couldn't get it to work for me. Could you post a complete working example?